# Why can't my user see environment variable?

Tags: bash, ssh, environment-variables

I have a .sh file with some environment variables under /etc/profile.d/vars.sh. Its content looks like this:

`export PORT=8080`

This is an Ubuntu 14.04 running on AWS EC2. When I log in via SSH with the default user (ubuntu) and run `echo $PORT` I get `8080` back.

However if I:

```
sudo su
su ubuntu
echo $PORT
```

I get nothing back. Why is that? How can I set environment variables for all my users (or specifically for ubuntu) so they will see it even in a non interactive shell session?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the -l option on su to get a full user login:

```
su -l ubuntu
```

That should give you the ubuntu environment you expect.